# How to get the bytes from a stream that I'm not writing to

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, stream

I'm writing a VB.net application (but you can answer in C# if you want, no problem) that uses a 3rd party .NET library. In particular, one method in this library takes an IO.Stream as input (among other things) and writes the results of its processing to said stream. My problem is that the method CLOSES the stream after writing to it, so I can't read back the data that it wrote in it!

To be more specific: it works, of course, if the stream is a FIeStream , since it writes the data on disk, but what if I want to read the data directly to memory? I tried using a MemoryStream, but as I said, when the method returns the stream is already closed, and I can't read back anything from it :(

EDIT: Solved by doing something similar to what "usr" suggested. Here's the code, if anyone needs it:

```
    Imports System.IO

Public Class CloseHijackedMemoryStream
    Inherits MemoryStream

    Public Overrides Sub Close()
        'We don't do anything, so the stream is still open
    End Sub

    Public Sub RealClose()
        MyBase.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why do you need to read back the bytes you just wrote to the other stream? In any event, those bytes will be the same as the stream you copied it from, so you could always reset the position of the original stream to get what you are looking for.

Comment: You should ask "how do I read whatever your code writes to the stream?" to the authors of the 3rd party component imho: they might have already thought about it and provide you suggestions

Comment: @Brian: As I said, *I* am not writing to the stream. A 3rd party application is. And it closes the stream once it has written to it, so I can't read back from it, it's "spent". I wanted to know if theres a way (or a particular type of stream) that can write to, say, a  previously supplied ByteArray, so when it is closed I have the written data available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a wrapper class around a stream that forwards all calls to the underlying (wrapped) stream but does not forward the Close and Dispose calls. That will prevent the library from closing it.

Derive from Stream, take an "inner stream" as a ctor arg and implement all methods by delegating to to the inner stream.

Comment: Marking this as accepted, as I did something similar while waiting for answers: rather than using a wrapper I actually just inherited MemoryStream and overridden the Close() method with an empty one, and added a "RealClose()" method that actually closes the stream. Will edit the main post to add the code in case anyone else needs it. THanks!

Answer (score 1):

The MemoryStream has an ToArray() method that returns its entire contents. I just did a quick test and it seems that that still works after closing (even after disposing)

Comment: +1 because it actually works O.o (even tho I used a different solution, as detailed in the 1st post). Didn't think of trying since the Read() methods raised exceptions...

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can create a custom type 'MyMemoryStream' from MemoryStream and override the Dispose and close method.

```
public class MyMemoryStream : MemoryStream
{
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Already chose answer before this was posted, but +1 anyway, since it's pretty much what I did while waiting for answers, thanks for the suggestion tho!